# Basic stock exchange simulator

Tags: c++

This is a simple stock exchange model.
There will be stock observers who are observing some specific stocks and multliple stocks can be registered at a stock exchange. Please advise how this implementation can be improved, I am not sure if the stock observer can subscribe to specific instruments?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
using namespace boost::signals2;

struct StockExchange
{
    signal<void(struct Event *)> events_;
};
struct StockObserver
{
    template <typename F>
    StockObserver(StockExchange &se, F &&func) : se_(se)
    {
        se_.events_.connect(func);
    }
    StockExchange &se_;
};
struct Event
{
    virtual ~Event() = default;
};
struct PriceTick : Event
{
    PriceTick(std::string_view name, double value) : name_(name), value_(value) {}

    std::string_view name_;
    double value_;
};
struct Stock
{
    Stock(std::string name, StockExchange &se) : name_(std::move(name)), se_(se) {}
    void setPrice(double value)
    {
        if (value == value_)
            return;
        PriceTick ps{name_, value};
        se_.events_(&ps);
        value_ = value;
    }
    std::string name_;
    double value_{0.0};
    StockExchange &se_;
};
int main()
{
    StockExchange se;
    StockObserver observer(se,
                    [](Event *e)
                    {
            auto ps = dynamic_cast<PriceTick*>(e);
            if(ps && ps->name_ == "SAM" && ps->value_ < 110)
               std::cout<<"I am buying 100 shares of : "<<ps->name_<< '\n'; });
    Stock sam("SAM", se);
    sam.setPrice(300);
    sam.setPrice(200);
    sam.setPrice(100);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "instruments"?

Comment: Hi there, I meant financial instrument. or differnt stock, so you can subscribe to "BB", and you receive notificiton about BB prices

Comment: Did you write this code? `I am not sure if the stock observer can subscribe to specific instruments?` seems to indicate that you did not write the code since you should be able to tell us what the observer does. You must be the author of the code to post it here.

Comment: @pacmaninbw, I wrote this code from scratch, what kind of question is that, this logic full fill 2 design patterns , observer and mediator, not expert in boost signal that's all!

Comment: the code as is each StockObserver will receive all evnets, which is not desirable, I am seeking if this can be filtered by any mean,

Comment: I found an answer here, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53d4633d585d8325

Answer (score 3):

### Architecture

1. There is no need to have a `StockExchange` class if you are interested in getting notifications for a single `Stock`. Instead just have a `signal` per stock and let the observer connect to it. I would also go so far as to have a signal per event.
2. The above point also solves the problem of having dangling references (I am talking about reference to `StockExchange` in `Stock`). I am assuming you want to keep track of a bunch of stock exchanges in the future. In this case, if you decide to put them all in a vector, then the moment the vector grows in capacity, all the references are invalidated and you have undefined behavior.
3. If you want to have a common `signal` for all `event`s, don't use dynamic polymorphism. `dynamic_cast` is considered a code smell; use `std::variant`or visitor pattern instead. It will force you to add cases to handle new events at compile time, instead of silently failing.
4. Consider using classes for better encapsulation, especially for `Stock`. Currently, anyone can just write to the `value_` instead of calling `setPrice` bypassing the signalling mechanism.

### Style/Code

1. Getters and Setters generally have the same name as the member. So change to member `value_` to `price_`.
2. Avoid `using namespace` in file scope. It is generally fine if it is a `.cpp` file. But in your case the different classes belong in their own files.
3. Prefer `auto var = Type{}` over `Type var` when creating a variable. This way it is impossible to have an uninitialized type. For plain old data types, the former is default-initialized whereas the latter is uninitialized.
4. Consider marking return types `[[nodiscard]]`.
5. There is no need to have `StockObserver` class. `boost::signals2` was released pre-C++11; that's why they have to create the class. You can just use a lambda directly.

Here is a version of the code with my changes incorporated:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

namespace bs = boost::signals2;

class Stock {
public:

    struct Events {
        bs::signal<void(double)> priceTick;
    };

    Stock(std::string name) : name_(std::move(name)) {}

    void setPrice(double value) {

        if (value == value_){
            return;
        }
        
        value_ = value;
        events_.priceTick(value);
    }

    double getPrice(double value) const {
        return value_;
    }

    Events & events() {
        return events_;
    }

private:

    std::string name_;
    double value_{0.0};

    Events events_ = {};
};

int main()
{
    auto sam = Stock("SAM");
    sam.events().priceTick.connect(
        [](double value) {
            if(value < 110) {
                std::cout<<  "I am buying 100 shares of : SAM \n";
            }
        }
    );
    
    sam.setPrice(300);
    sam.setPrice(200);
    sam.setPrice(100);
}
```

### Random

1. Generally, financial data is not stored in `double` or `float` but stored as some kind of fixed point number. Consider creating a `FixedPoint` type.

Answer (score 2):

## Subscribing to specific events

> I am not sure if the stock observer can subscribe to specific instruments?

In your code, no, because there is only one signal slot that is used for all stock market events. There are several solutions possible if you want to limit which subscribers get notified based on instrument or other parameters:

1. Just make multiple signal slots. You don't have to hardcode them; you can for example make a map of stock names to slots:

   ```
   struct StockExchange {
       std::unordered_map<std::string, signal<…>> events;
   };
   ```

   It's relatively easy and quite efficient, the drawback is that it doesn't scale when you want to make this work for more parameters than just the stock name.
2. Implement your own signal slot class that keeps track of what events listeners are interested in, so they only get signaled when needed.
3. Create an adapter for the signal handlers that only calls the lambda when certain conditions are met. For example:

   ```
   auto when_stock_below(std::string name, double threshold, auto function) {
       return [=](Event *e) {
           if (auto ps = dynamic_cast<PriceTick*>(e);
                    ps && ps->name_ == name && ps->value_ < threshold) {
               function(ps);
           }
       }
   }
   …
   StockExchange se;
   StockObserver observer(se, when_stock_below("SAM", 110, [](PriceTick *ps) {
       std::cout << "I am buying 100 shares of : " << ps->name_<< '\n';
   });
   ```

   It will still cause every registered signal handler to be called, but it does simplify registering for specific events.
4. Create a broker for events: something that connects to `StockExchange`'s signal slot, but then distributes it amongst other signal slots it creates itself. For example:

   ```
   struct EventTypeBroker {
       signal<void(struct PriceTick*)> priceticks_;
       …

       EventTypeBroker(StockExchange& se) {
           se.events_.connect([this](Event* e) {
               if (auto ps = dynamic_cast<PriceTick*>(e)) {
                   priceticks_(ps);
               } else {
                   …
               }
           }
       }
   };

   struct PriceTickNameBroker {
       std::unordered_map<std::string, signal<void(struct PriceTick*)>> stocks_;
       …
   };
   …
   StockExchange se;
   EventTypeBroker evb(se);
   PriceTickNameBroker ptnb(evb);
   ptnb.stocks_["SAM"].connect([](PriceTick *ps) {
       if (ps->value < 110)
           std::cout << "I am buying 100 shares of : " << ps->name_<< '\n';
   });
   ```

   This generalizes option 1 and makes it more scalable.
5. A combination of the above.

Ajinkya Kamat mentioned using `std::variant` instead of using polymorphism; the above is compatible with that.